# How to import posts from wordpress into October CMS

Tags: wordpress, import, octobercms

What would be the way to import posts and pages from a wordpress site into a clean installation of october CMS?

Answer (score 1):

someone start a projet on github to do it: https://github.com/tiipiik/Import

> Version 1.0.1
>
> Import WordPress content into OctoberCMS. WP posts are considered as
>   October pages, not October CMS blog pages.

Maybe this can help